# multiple actions need to be perform in single selector

Tags: jquery, html

The case :

I've a list items that manipulate css for the selected one to apply 'selected effect'. For example once for any specified li were clicked, it run this code :

```
    $(document).on( 'click', 'li', function (){      
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

but on the li, it needs to perform other action because I have another link inside the li:

```
<li class="selected"><a href="#"><span class="items">Item 1</span></a><a href="#"><span class="edit">edit</span></a></li>
```

[image: this]

my question :

How to avoid to call the click function when I click on the other links (for example 'edit' above)? because my intention is not to select the li..

I thought of inside the click function, I can put an 'if expression' for when not the edit link were clicked, then proceed..

but I look for if any better way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to avoid to call the click function when I click on the other links (for example 'edit' above)?

In your handler for the "edit" link, use `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent it bubbling to the `li`.

Since you're using delegation, you can do that like this: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/aqumih/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/aqumih/1/edit)

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
    $("<p>Do the edit...</p>").appendTo(document.body);
    event.stopPropagation();             // <=== The important bit
}).on('click', 'li', function (){
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    return false;
});
```

(I also added `return false` to the second one because the links in the `li`s were causing the page to jump.)

Comment: if these two are seprated function, will they still work with just     event.stopPropagation(); added into?

Comment: @NurulLia: Yes. (Note that they *are* separate functions above.) Also note that it doesn't matter what order you attach them ([example](http://jsbin.com/aqumih/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/aqumih/2/edit)). Order *would* be important if you used delegation for one of them and a direct handler for the other, so if you're using delegation for the `li`s, I would use delegation for the edit links as well.

Comment: what if I want to code like separate the edit as another function?

function editItem(e) {
//code
}

Comment: @NurulLia: Just use that function name rather than the anonymous function above, e.g., `$(document).on('click', '.edit', editItem)`. Within that function, be sure to call `stopPropagation()` on the event object (you called it `e` in your comment, so it would be `e.stopPropagation();`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create two separate handlers for the two anchor links within your li.

for e.g :

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.items', function (e) {
     //Items handler
     $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$(document).on( 'click', '.edit', function (e) { 
     //edit handler
     $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the handler with an event target:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'li', function (e) { 
    $elem = $(e.target);
    if ($elem.hasClass('edit')) {
        // your handler for edit...
    } else {
        // check for other conditions or elements if you need...

        $('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```